# On Back Press button call back function is not working in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi All I have been trying to implement the Willpopscope in Flutter but still this call back function is not working, it still closes or goes back to the previous screen and I want to show the alert dialog when ever the user presses the back button, but the instead of showing the dialog it goes back to the previous screen. Please help me where I am doing wrong.

**EDIT CODE**

```
import 'package:deep6/audio_player/click_player.dart';
import 'package:deep6/main_menu.dart';
import 'package:deep6/utility/countDown.dart';
import 'package:deep6/utility/preference.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import
   'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SceneStory extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scene(
    character: null,
    text: null,
    mainTextColor: null,
    avatar: null,
    lbText: null,
    lbTextTarget: null,
    lbTextColor: null,
    rbText: null,
    rbTextTarget: null,
    rbTextColor: null,
  ),
);
}
}

class Scene extends StatefulWidget {
 List<String> character = new List<String>();
 List<String> text = new List<String>();
 List<List<int>> mainTextColor = new List<List<int>>();
 List<String> avatar = new List<String>();
 List<String> lbText = new List<String>();
 List<int> lbTextTarget = new List<int>();
 List<List<int>> lbTextColor = new List<List<int>>();
 List<String> rbText = new List<String>();
 List<int> rbTextTarget = new List<int>();
 List<List<int>> rbTextColor = new List<List<int>>();
 Scene(
  {Key key,
  this.character,
  this.text,
  this.mainTextColor,
  this.avatar,
  this.lbText,
  this.lbTextTarget,
  this.lbTextColor,
  this.rbText,
  this.rbTextTarget,
  this.rbTextColor})
  : super(key: key);

 @override
 SceneState createState() => new SceneState();
 }

String name, text, buttonLeftText, buttonRightText;
String avatar = 'assets/images/profile_cure.png';
int sceneId, leftTarget, rightTarget;

class SceneState extends State<Scene> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
 double width, height;
 List<String> content = new List<String>();
 CountDown customTimer;
 PrefsKeys prefs;
 int mainIndex = 0;
 bool isEnabled = false;
 List<String> character = new List<String>();
 List<String> text = new List<String>();
 List<List<int>> mainTextColor = new List<List<int>>();
 List<String> avatar = new List<String>();
 List<String> lbText = new List<String>();
 List<int> lbTextTarget = new List<int>();
 List<List<int>> lbTextColor = new List<List<int>>();
 List<String> rbText = new List<String>();
 List<int> rbTextTarget = new List<int>();
 List<List<int>> rbTextColor = new List<List<int>>();

 Image charImage;
 Text charName, mainText, leftText, rightText;
 MaterialButton leftButton, rightButton;
 ClickPlayer cPlay;

 AnimationController controller;

 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
character = widget.character;
text = widget.text;
mainTextColor = widget.mainTextColor;
avatar = widget.avatar;
lbText = widget.lbText;
lbTextTarget = widget.lbTextTarget;
lbTextColor = widget.lbTextColor;
rbText = widget.rbText;
rbTextTarget = widget.rbTextTarget;
rbTextColor = widget.rbTextColor;
animation();
cPlay = new ClickPlayer();
preference();
}

void preference() async {
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((pref) 
{
  pref.setBool(PrefsKeys.bool_continuation, true);
});
}

void animation() async {
controller = new AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 4000), vsync: this);
await controller.forward();
controller.dispose();
}

Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
if (payload != null) {
  debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
}
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => MenuScreen(),
  ),
);
print("Notifications is Clicked  $payload");
}

void showNotification() async {
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
var initializationSettingsAndroid;
var initializationSettingsIOS;
var initializationSettings;
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
    initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    selectNotification: onSelectNotification);
var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
    new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(minutes: 2));
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
    '0', 'Anas', 'Notification',
    importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High);
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
    0,
    'DEEP 6',
    'NOW YOU CAN CONTINUE.',
    scheduledNotificationDateTime,
    platformChannelSpecifics);
print("Inside Notifications class");
}

void leftButtonClick() async {
cPlay.playClick();
mainIndex = lbTextTarget[mainIndex];
print("$mainIndex mainindex");
if (mainIndex == 18) {
  showNotification();
  SharedPreferences pref =
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((pref) {
    pref.setInt(
        PrefsKeys.str_timestamp, new 
    DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    pref.setString(PrefsKeys.str_character, character[mainIndex]);
    pref.setString(PrefsKeys.str_mainText, text[mainIndex]);
    pref.setString(PrefsKeys.str_avatar, avatar[mainIndex]);
    pref.setString(PrefsKeys.str_lbText, lbText[mainIndex]);

    List<String> color = new List<String>();
    color.add(mainTextColor[mainIndex][0].toString());
    color.add(mainTextColor[mainIndex][1].toString());
    color.add(mainTextColor[mainIndex][2].toString());
    pref.setStringList(PrefsKeys.list_color, color);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MainMenu(),
      ),
    );
    });
    } else {
    isEnabled = false;
    setState(() {
    charImage = null;
    charName = null;
    mainText = null;
    leftText = null;
    rightText = null;
    charImage = new Image.asset(
      avatar[mainIndex],
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      height: height * 0.2,
    );
    charName = new Text(
      character[mainIndex],
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(mainTextColor[mainIndex][0],
            mainTextColor[mainIndex][1], mainTextColor[mainIndex][2], 
      1.0),
        fontSize: 20.0,
      ),
      );

      mainText = new Text(
      text[mainIndex],
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(mainTextColor[mainIndex][0],
            mainTextColor[mainIndex][1], mainTextColor[mainIndex][2], 
         1.0),
        fontSize: 22.0,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    );
    animation();
    leftText = new Text(
      lbText[mainIndex],
      style: new TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(lbTextColor[mainIndex][0],
              lbTextColor[mainIndex][1], lbTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0)),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      softWrap: true,
      maxLines: 10,
    );
    if (rbText[mainIndex] == "") {
      rightText = null;
      rightButton = new MaterialButton(
        key: null,
        onPressed: () {},
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
        height: 0.0,
        minWidth: 0.0,
        child: null,
      );
    } else {
      rightText = new Text(
        rbText[mainIndex],
        style: new TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(rbTextColor[mainIndex][0],
              rbTextColor[mainIndex][1], rbTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0),
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  });
}
}

void rightButtonClick() async {
cPlay.playClick();
mainIndex = rbTextTarget[mainIndex];
print("$mainIndex mainindex");
if (mainIndex == 18) {
  showNotification();
  SharedPreferences pref =
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((pref) {
    pref.setInt(
        PrefsKeys.str_timestamp, new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MainMenu(),
      ),
    );
  });
} else {
  isEnabled = false;
  setState(() {
    charImage = null;
    charName = null;
    mainText = null;
    leftText = null;
    rightText = null;
    charImage = new Image.asset(
      avatar[mainIndex],
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      height: height * 0.2,
    );
    charName = new Text(
      character[mainIndex],
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(mainTextColor[mainIndex][0],
            mainTextColor[mainIndex][1], mainTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0),
        fontSize: 22.0,
      ),
    );

    mainText = new Text(
      text[mainIndex],
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(mainTextColor[mainIndex][0],
            mainTextColor[mainIndex][1], mainTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0),
        fontSize: 20.0,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    );
    animation();
    leftText = new Text(
      lbText[mainIndex],
      style: new TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(lbTextColor[mainIndex][0],
              lbTextColor[mainIndex][1], lbTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0)),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      softWrap: true,
      maxLines: 10,
    );
    if (rbText[mainIndex] == "") {
      rightText = null;
      rightButton = new MaterialButton(
        key: null,
        onPressed: () {},
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
        height: 0.0,
        minWidth: 0.0,
        child: null,
      );
    } else {
      rightText = new Text(
        rbText[mainIndex],
        style: new TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(rbTextColor[mainIndex][0],
              rbTextColor[mainIndex][1], rbTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0),
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  });
}
}

Future<bool> _showDialog() {
print("Show dialog");
return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext contxt) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: new Text(
          "Exit!!!",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        content: new Text(
          "Are You sure you want to exit?",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text(
              "Yes",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            onPressed: null,
          )
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
  width = mediaQueryData.size.width;
  height = mediaQueryData.size.height;

  Animation<int> _characterCount = new StepTween(
        begin: 0, end: text[mainIndex].length)
    .animate(new CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeIn));
controller.addStatusListener((status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    isEnabled = true;
  }
});

charImage = new Image.asset(
  avatar[mainIndex],
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  height: height * 0.2,
);
charName = new Text(
  character[mainIndex],
  style: new TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(mainTextColor[mainIndex][0],
        mainTextColor[mainIndex][1], mainTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0),
    fontSize: 22.0,
  ),
);

mainText = new Text(
  text[mainIndex],
  style: new TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(mainTextColor[mainIndex][0],
        mainTextColor[mainIndex][1], mainTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0),
    fontSize: 20.0,
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
);
leftText = new Text(
  lbText[mainIndex],
  style: new TextStyle(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(lbTextColor[mainIndex][0],
          lbTextColor[mainIndex][1], lbTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0)),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  softWrap: true,
  maxLines: 10,
);
rightText = new Text(
  rbText[mainIndex],
  style: new TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(rbTextColor[mainIndex][0],
        rbTextColor[mainIndex][1], rbTextColor[mainIndex][2], 1.0),
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
);
leftButton = new MaterialButton(
  key: null,
  onPressed: () {
    if (isEnabled) {
      leftButtonClick();
    }
  },
  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
  height: height * 0.2,
  minWidth: width * 0.49,
  child: new Container(
    child: leftText,
  ),
);
rightButton = new MaterialButton(
  key: null,
  onPressed: () {
    if (isEnabled) {
      rightButtonClick();
    }
  },
  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
  height: height * 0.2,
  minWidth: width * 0.49,
  child: rightText,
);

return new WillPopScope(
  child: new Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF000000),
    body: new Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage('assets/images/blury_background.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.fill)),
      child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            charImage,
            new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
              child: new Center(
                child: charName,
              ),
              color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
            ),
            new AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _characterCount,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  String txt =
                      text[mainIndex].substring(0, _characterCount.value);
                  return new Container(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
                    child: new Text(
                      txt,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(
                            mainTextColor[mainIndex][0],
                            mainTextColor[mainIndex][1],
                            mainTextColor[mainIndex][2],
                            1.0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    //fromLTRB(12.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0),

                    height: height * 0.5,
                  );
                }),
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  child: leftButton,
                ),
                new Container(
                  child: rightButton,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
    ),
  ),
  onWillPop: () {
    print("on back is pressed");
  },
);
}
}
```

Here is my code of the whole class. Please help me now that where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you add some code - where exactly do you call this `return new WillPopScope`

Answer (score 3):

Try to wrap only `body` in `WillPopScope`, not the whole `Scaffold`

**UPD**

If I understand correct - you call this screen this way:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SceneStory()));
```

Do it that way

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scene()));
```

Comment: i didn't exactly understand what are you trying to tell me.

Comment: You know - it's strange. I've tried your code and it works - dialog's been shown...

Comment: I am editing my question with complete class code please have a look at it

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. You return `WillPopScope` from build method and it have to work... I don't know. Maybe you can create some test screen in your app - just empty scaffold for testing willpopscope

Comment: just for testing i am using this same method on different class it is working on that class but it is not working in this class and I dont know why :(

Comment: So, why do you need `SceneStory`?

Comment: I have removed the SceneStory but still no progress.